# can't resolve module from app.module.ts using Ionic2 RC3

Tags: ionic2

Ok, I'm lost.  Been messing with this for days.  I have an app that was working in beta 10 and i'm trying to migrate to RC3.  I'm getting the following error

```
C:\Projects\db>ionic build browser
******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************

> dynamicbible@2.0.0 ionic:build C:\Projects\db
> ionic-app-scripts build

[10:33:33]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.45
[10:33:33]  build prod started ...
[10:33:33]  clean started ...
[10:33:33]  clean finished in 5 ms
[10:33:33]  copy started ...
[10:33:33]  ngc started ...
[10:33:33]  copy finished in 192 ms
[10:33:37]  can't resolve module ../components/dcl-wrapper/dcl-wrapper.ts from C:/Projects/db/.tmp/app/app.module.ts
[10:33:37]  Error: Source file C:/Projects/db/.tmp/components/dcl-wrapper/dcl-wrapper.ts not present in program.,
            resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Projects/db/.tmp/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in
            C:/Projects/db/.tmp/app/app.module.ts
[10:33:37]  ngc failed
[10:33:37]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
[10:33:37]  Error: Error

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "ionic:build" "--"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! dynamicbible@2.0.0 ionic:build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
```

But the dcl-wrapper.ts file does exist in the exact place its telling me it doesn't.  Here is the relevant paths:

```
C:\Projects\db\src\components\dcl-wrapper\dcl-wrapper.ts
C:\Projects\db\src\app\app.module.ts`
```

and here is my app.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import {SearchPage} from "../pages/search/search";
import {DclWrapper} from "../components/dcl-wrapper/dcl-wrapper.ts";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        SearchPage,
        DclWrapper
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        SearchPage
    ],
    providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and my dcl-wrapper.ts

```
//our root app component
import {Component, Compiler, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild, Input, ComponentRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core'

// Helper component to add dynamic components
@Component({
    selector: 'dcl-wrapper',
    template: `<div #target></div>`
})
export class DclWrapper {
    @ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) target;
    @Input() type;
    @Input() data;
    cmpRef: ComponentRef<any>;
    private isViewInitialized: boolean = false;

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private compiler: Compiler,
        private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    updateComponent() {
        if (!this.isViewInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.cmpRef) {
            this.cmpRef.destroy();
        }

        let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.type);
        this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory)
        // to access the created instance use
        // this.compRef.instance.someProperty = 'someValue';
        // this.compRef.instance.someOutput.subscribe(val => doSomething());
        this.cmpRef.instance.item = this.data;

        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.updateComponent();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.isViewInitialized = true;
        this.updateComponent();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.cmpRef) {
            this.cmpRef.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

I have verified that the files do exist in the same structure in the .tmp dir that is created during the build process.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For whats its worth, everything builds when I run ionic serve.  So there is some kind of disparity between ionic's build option and the serve option.

Answer (score 2):

The error is at line:

`import {DclWrapper} from "../components/dcl-wrapper/dcl-wrapper.ts";`

The correct way is:

`import {DclWrapper} from "../components/dcl-wrapper/dcl-wrapper";`

(without ".ts")